# intersecting pandas dataframe with list of terms in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe for a term x document matrix. I need to extract only those values that appear in a separate list of terms (extracted from a different source).

The list TestDict contains terms. E.g., ['аборенков','абсолютно',...]

-- to create a term by document matrix (reused)

```
def fn_tdm_df(docs, xColNames = None, **kwargs):

    #initialize the  vectorizer
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(**kwargs)
    x1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)
    #create dataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(x1.toarray().transpose(), index = vectorizer.get_feature_names())
    if xColNames is not None:
        df.columns = xColNames

    return df
```

Then later in the code I have:

```
for filename in os.listdir(DIR):
     d1 = fn_tdm_df(docs = MyCorpus(DIR)['docs'])
```

The output of d1.head(5):

```
             0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  27  28  29  30  31  \
аборенков    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   
аборенкова   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   
абсолютно    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1 ...   0   0   0   0   0   
авантюру     0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   
аварии       0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   

            32  33  34  35  36  
аборенков    0   0   0   2   0  
аборенкова   0   0   0   1   0  
абсолютно    0   0   0   0   0  
авантюру     0   0   0   0   0  
аварии       0   0   0   0   0
```

I'm doing something like:

```
with open("TestTD", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
     for w in d1.index: # d1 is my dataframe
          if w in TestDict:    
               np.savetxt(f, d1.loc(w),fmt='%d')
```

But I don't think the .loc(w) is what I want...

Comment: No, it isn't. I want to see a [mcve].

Comment: added more code

Comment: Code != [mcve]. Where is your data? Please print `df.head(10)` and paste it here. What is your expected output? Do you think you have provided enough information to answer your question?

Comment: Good point. Sorry. Here it goes:

Comment: No, no, no... it goes in your question!

Comment: Will add to the question. Cannot add here.

Comment: You haven't added `TestDict`?

Comment: I added TestDict.